# how to get equation from arithmetic progression

Tags: calculus

I need to find the equation of $$a_n= 2*a_{n-1}+2 $$
$$a_1 = 2 $$

if not possible to find the exact equation close one will be good enough. for example if I get $$y=3.5x+2$$ I can make it $$y=x$$. $$y=5x^2+7x+5$$ can make it $$y=x^2$$ etc...

Comment: what's  $$a_0$$? $$a_1= 2$$

Comment: Edit that into the question & then calculate the first few values ... I bet you will quickly guess the answer & then prove it by induction.

Comment: $a_1=2,a_2=6,a_3=14,\cdots$ can you guess what the answer is ? Big hint : https://oeis.org/A000918

Comment: Your equation is a relatively simple example of a linear, non-homogenous recurrence relation. There are techniques to solve these types of questions in many cases, such as those outlined at [Solutions of Linear Nonhomogeneous Recurrence Relations](http://staff.scem.uws.edu.au/cgi-bin/cgiwrap/zhuhan/dmath/dm_readall.cgi?page=24). However, as Donald has suggested in the comment above, your question is simple enough that you don't necessarily need to use these more general techniques.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit  $$2^n-2$$ is the exact equation. how did you get it?and what is the web?
the only problem is that $$a_2$$ is our $$a_1$$ can we fix that?

Comment: Just shift $n$ by $1$ ...\begin{eqnarray*}
2^{n-1}-2
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: oh lol nice :)!!  it's actually n+1 but I got the idea. how did you did that and how did you use this site for that?

Answer (score 1):

The terms of your sequence are $$2,4+2,8+4+2,16+8+4+2,...$$

$$2,6,14,30,62,...$$
A formula is easily found to be $$ a_n =2^{n+1}-2$$